# Surface Pro 4 : Secure Boot ERROR

Tags: microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I got a big problem with Surface Pro 4 Secure Boot.

I disabled the Secure Boot in order to boot to the Ubuntu live USB drive and install Ubuntu in the hard drive. If I didn't disable Secure Boot, it won't boot from the Ubuntu USB.

However, when I tried to factory reset the device, I cannot enable it again and it keeps showing me red bar on the top of the screen which makes me angry.

When I try to enable secure boot it shows me this:

"Secure Boot error"

"The system failed to update the Secure Boot certificate keyset. The state of Secure Boot on this system has not been modified. Please reboot the system to try again, or open Surface UEFI settings and select a diffrent Secure Boot certificate keyset."

I tried to factory reset by a recovery image, but it still doesn't work.

Help!

Comment: So have you tried to do what it says to do?

Comment: Yes.. still doesn't work.. OTL